# working with NamedEntityGraph

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 levels of entity sample: Year -> Class -> Students, something like this

```
@Entity
public class Year {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="year_id")
  Set<Class> classes;
}

@Entity
public class Class {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="class_id")
  Set<Student> students;
}

@Entity
public class Student {
  String name;
}
```

So I create in my Year class a entityGraph

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Year.classes",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("classes"))
```

But in some methods in my service I wanna only to return a classes so I put in my repository

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Year.classes", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
public List<Year> findOne(){
}
```

but in some methods in my service I wanna return the 3 levels

in this case I need to create a @NameEntityGraph in my Class too (and configure to return a Students)

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Class.students",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("students"))
```

so how can I configure that method to return the students too?

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Year.classes", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
public List<Year> findTwo(){
}
```

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Class.students` graph needs to be defined and referenced as a subgraph in a new `EntityGraph` for the class `Year`. Something like this should work:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Year.full",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(
        value = "classes", 
        subgraph = "Class.students"),
    subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(
        name = "Class.students", 
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("students")
    )
)
```

[Here you can read more about this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/)

Comment: Nice. and you know if it's possible to have more than one subgraphs to another level of entity? sample 4 levels. tks

Comment: since `subgraphs` is an array it should be possible.